# how do I get a repository instance from nestjs standalone app

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a nestjs app, and am writing some stand alone tasks to go along with it.

The [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications) for standalone apps shows how to get instances of services i.e.

```js
const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
const tasksService = app.get(TasksService);
```

but doesn't show how to get a repository if I wanted to read/write to the db.

I've tried the obvious:

```js
const repo = app.get(Repository<User>);
```

but this throws the compiler error "Value of type 'typeof Repository' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)".

The examples online (and in the nestjs docs) use @InjectRepository but my standalone task doesn't have any which can use that, sadly.

How do I get a repository instance I can use to read/write to the db in a standalone nestjs script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.get` receives a token of the provider. Then, if you're trying to get some custom repository from `@nestjs/typeorm`, just retrieve its token using [`getRepositoryToken(User)`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing)

thus,

`const repo = app.get(getRepositoryToken(User));`

should work

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Another answer to my question would be 'what exactly are you trying to do?' because all I wanted to do was query/insert entities, and in nestjs you can do that directly from the entity type itself.

i.e.

instead of

```js
const repo = app.get(getRepositoryToken(User));

...

const users = repo.find()
```

I could just do

```js
const users = User.find()
```

which saves some gnarly setup code, and removes some imports.